# eas build -p android fails with error Plugin with id 'maven' not found

Tags: android, react-native, expo, build.gradle, upgrade

I had app created by react native expo totally managed by expo
I used to build by expo build but it has been superseded so I used eas build -p android
I upgrade the SDK for the app after that I got error
[image]

"expo": "^45.0.0",

"react-native": "^0.68.2",

"expo-cli": "^5.4.4",

Comment: try deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and reinstalling with `npm i`. @unimodules is deprecated and expo 45 does not use it

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @DomBarker before these line there was a package cause this issue, I removed it and the problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before these lines of error I found the location package cause the error so I reinstall it and the problem solved